# TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbName' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, mongodb-atlas

I've tried to connect my Loopback application with MongoDb Atlas, but I'm having an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbName' of null".

Below is what I've tried:

1. run lb data source
2. Fill all the required info
3. Generated this javascript object:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "mongodb"
  },
  "mongodb": {
    "host": "",
    "port": 0,
    "url": "mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@DATABASENAME-f4exx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "database": "DATABASENAME",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "name": "mongodb",
    "user": "dbAdmin",
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "connector": "mongodb"
  }
}
```

4. On every attempt to run "node ." , getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dbName' of null`.
5. I've added my IP in the whitelisted IPs (MongoDB atlas)
6. Below is my model.config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mongodb",
    "public": false
  }
}
```

PS: I'm using loopback 3x

Comment: can you post the model-config.json ?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty done

Comment: Where are you using the `dbName`? search the word `dbName` in your entire project directory and attach the file where it is used. I think if you are using a boilerplate of some sort it maybe there somewhere.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty the only place where I found dbName is in the mongodb.js at line 310

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that setting the property `"useNewUrlParser": true` to false solved my issue. Still don't know why this was the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put special character in your password, if you are using old mongodb